# MVC3 CKEditor and Ajax issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I have the following action/controller on MVC3:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AX_AddItemResponse(ItemResponsesVM response)
    {
        return View(response);
    }
```

This is the viewmodel that im using:

```
public class ItemResponsesVM
    {
        [Display(Name = "Message")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message is required")]
        [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Please add a maximum of 250 chars")]
        public string Message
        { get; set; }
     }
```

For other hand i have this ajax call that should go to the action described above:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form=$("#MyForm"),
    $("#Submitbutton").click(function () {

        $('#Message').each(function () {
            var $textarea = $(this);
            $textarea.val(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getClearText());
        })
        ,
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("AX_AddItemResponse","Responses"))",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert("AllGood");
            }
            ,
            error:function()
            {
                alert("AllBad");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Im using the CKEditor to enhance the textarea with id="Message" element, the problem is that **i dont know how to serialize the form** in order to reach the action described with an instance of  ItemResponsesVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already correctly serializing the form:

```
data: form.serialize()
```

Just make sure you decorate your `Message` property with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute or the ASP.NET runtime might reject the request if it contains dangerous characters such as `<`, `>`, ...:

```
public class ItemResponsesVM
{
    [Display(Name = "Message")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message is required")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Please add a maximum of 250 chars")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Also there seems to be some comma (`,`) before the `$.ajax` call which should be a  semi-colon (`;`).

Comment: @Jose3d, yes, and next time please use some javascript debugging tool such as FireBug as it tells you everything about an AJAX call and why it might fail.